# Forming a 3-digit number from a set of 5 digits, given restrictions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The given question is:

A three-digit number is formed from the digits 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 (no repetitions allowed). Find the probability that…

a) the number contains the digits 3 and 5.

b) the number contains the digits 3 or 5.

For part a), using my knowledge of combinatorics, I did: $\frac{\left(3\cdot3!\right)}{60}=\frac{3}{10}$ . For part b), I did: $\frac{2\left(\binom{3}{2}\cdot3!\right)}{60}=\frac{3}{5}$ .

I am unsure if I am correct and feel as if I have made an error in my working/answer, thus I would appreciate it if someone could please verify my working and assist be in correcting my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: You have some tools to control what you did. The number can contain 3 and 5, only 3, only 5, or neither 3 nor 5. You can count probability for each option, and check that the sum is 1.

Comment: You should explain your reasoning.  That makes it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A three-digit number is formed from the digits $3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ (no repetitions allowed).  Find the probability that the number contains the digits $3$ and $5$.

Your answer is correct.  There are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$ ways to form a three-digit number containing three distinct digits drawn from the five-element set $S = \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$.  If such a number contains both the digits $3$ and $5$, it must contain one of the other three digits in the set $S$.  Since there are $3!$ ways to arrange three distinct digits, the number of favorable cases is $3 \cdot 3!$.  Hence, the probability that a three-digit number containing three distinct digits from the set $S$ contains the digits $3$ and $5$ is indeed
$$\Pr(\text{contains the digits $3$ and $5$}) = \frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot 3!}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}$$

> A three-digit number is formed from the digits $3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ (no repetitions allowed).  Find the probability that the number contains the digits $3$ or $5$.

As @Lourrran pointed out in the comments, a three-digit number containing three distinct digits drawn from set $S$ contains the digits $3$ or $5$ unless it contains neither $3$ nor $5$.  Therefore, to find the probability that a three-digit number with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ contains $3$ or $5$, we can subtract the probability that it contains neither $3$ nor $5$ from $1$.  Since set $S$ has only five digits, a number containing neither $3$ nor $5$ must contain the digits $4, 6, 7$.  There are $3!$ ways to arrange these digits, so
$$\Pr(\text{number contains neither the digits $3$ nor $5$}) = \frac{3!}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}$$
Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{number contains digits $3$ or $5$}) = 1 - \frac{3!}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}$$

*What did you do wrong?*

While you have not explained your reasoning, I suspect that you tried to add the number of three-digit numbers with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contain a $3$ and the number of three-digit numbers with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contain a $5$.  If so, you made an error in this calculation.  Moreover, if you had done that calculation correctly, your answer would be too large since simply adding these two cases would count each three-digit number with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contains both a $3$ and a $5$ twice.  Therefore, you would have to subtract your answer from the first question from the total.

*Number of three-digit numbers with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contain the digit $3$*:  If the number contains a $3$, it must contain two of the other four digits in set $S$.  Since there are $3!$ ways to arrange three distinct digits, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}3!$$
such numbers.

*Number of three-digit numbers with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contain the digit $5$*:  By symmetry, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}3!$$
such numbers.

*Number of three-digit numbers with distinct digits drawn from set $S$ that contain both the digits $3$ and $5$*:  As we found above, there are
$$\binom{3}{1}3!$$
such numbers.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$2\binom{4}{2}3! - \binom{3}{1}3!$$

Therefore,
$$\Pr(\text{number contains digits $3$ or $5$}) = \frac{2\binom{4}{2}3! - \binom{3}{1}3!}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}$$